# Maths equation: 357568588-11 = ~357568584.858

Tags: mathematics

Move one line and make this true: $357568588-11 = $ ~ $357568584.858...$

No cross through the "=" sign stuff.

Hint:

> It can be ANY line

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _line_. Are you referring to any straight line, or any single digit? Like can I move the top of the `7` making it a `/` and moving the top part elsewhere?

Comment: @Tas the question's hint tells you that, and it's been answered. Nicely, the line can keep its shape.

Comment: To a mathematician (who is not a topologist), a "line" is always a *straight* line. You are thinking about a *curve*.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand This is interesting. In Brazil, in Math contexts, you rarely refer to that shape as a "line" - instead, you use the name "Reta", which specifically means a _straight line_. If written in portuguese, this puzzle would be far easier to figure out since your brain wouldn't link the math straight line and the word line immediately.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand I’m not a mathematician or a topologist I didn’t know that it meant only a straight line I’m so sorry if I offended you I will never do anything of the sort ever again 

Comment: Well, in English this distinction is commonly used. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve. And https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_curves.

Comment: Come on, it’s just one riddle, I’ll specify curves as well next time

Comment: @RohitJose: No problem at all! I didn't mean to take focus from the riddle! :)

Comment: It's ok, I didn't know that lines in geometry only meant straight lines. Thanks for telling me!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

One can move...

> the tilde (~) and place it "on top" of the 11 to make the mathematical symbol $\pi$: $357568588−\pi = 357568584.858...$

Comment: Correct! Well done!